# Type I error level vs. sample size

Tags: hypothesis-testing, sample-size, type-i-and-ii-errors

From Jay and Devore's Modern Mathematical Statistics, Chapter 9, problem 61 c

> In most situations, would it be reasonable to
> use a level .01 test in conjunction with a sample
> size of 40,000? Why or why not?

Answer in the back of the book:

> Because the null hypothesis will be rejected with high
> probability, even with only slight departure from the
> null hypothesis, it is not very useful to do a .01 level
> test.

My guess is that this is saying that for a non-minuscule effect size and huge sample, setting the type I error at 10^-2 results in a type II error of 10^-10 which is a suboptimal trade off between the two.

Is that what they mean?

Comment: Of possible interest: Betensky, Rebecca A. "The p-value requires context, not a threshold." The American Statistician 73.sup1 (2019): 115-117. https://www.tandfonline.com/doi/pdf/10.1080/00031305.2018.1529624

Comment: In decding the critical value for a test, there is almost always a trade-off between probabilities of Type I Error and Type II Error. If you move the critical value to increase the Rejection region, then P(Type I error) increases and P(Type II error) decreases. // One strategy is to try to make the two error probabilities about equal (and by choosing large enough sample size n) both small enough that the test is useful.